# How to EXCLUDE a directory from a pathPatttern

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have found many ways to set pathPatterns to apply to certain directories or files. I need to **EXCLUDE** a directory from a general pattern.

I have an InstantApp intent-filter with a `pathPattern="/.*"` That allows two ways of passing parameters with the download of the instantapp feature `module`, `viz`., `example.com/abc/xyz` or `example.com/?Q1=abc&Q2=xyz`.

My problem is that I need a directory, say, `example.com/exclusion` NOT to be treated as a parameter to be passed but as **BROWSABLE**.

Any ideas or am I asking the impossible? BTW I do not want to move my pathPattern to, say, `"/insertion/.*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you prefix your path pattern with a value like :
pathPattern="/**included**/.*"

So you add it in the manifest to handle only this one.

Examples :

example.com/**included**/abc/xyz

example.com/**included**/?Q1=abc&Q2=xyz

so this one (the excluded) :

example.com/exclusion

it will not be manage by the application.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I ended up doing. The bottom line is that the Instant App "root" must be a subdirectory of the domain if you want the rest of it, e.g., example.com/* to act as a normal website. Fortunately, that does not require moving the .wellknown directory and the DAL.

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas or am I asking the impossible?

You are asking the impossible. You can have multiple `pathPattern` values in an additive fashion, but there are no subtraction semantics in `<intent-filter>` in general.

Comment: Thank you so much. I suspected as much because I was coming up empty. I was hoping that there might be an ingenious combination of path and pathPatterns that might accomplish it.